# Using Anaconda for a parent image for Docker?

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile

I'm trying to slightly modify the Docker tutorial to use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/) as a parent image in my Dockerfile. This runs into one small problem, which is that the following statement:

```
FROM continuumio:anaconda3
```

doesn't work.

I get

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  71.17kB
Step 1/7 : FROM continuumio:anaconda3
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while     waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

when I use the

```
docker build
```

command.

Comment: The image you are trying to access is protected, are you logged in to the registry? Try doing `docker pull continuumio:anaconda3` and post a comment here with result, I'm getting a authorization error. Maybe you should try later because the registry might simply be unaccessible for some time due to many possible causes.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that it was protected, I just Googled Docker Anaconda and tried to pull the first thing I saw. How would I set up a Docker image with an Anaconda parent, then?

Comment: Actually there is something wrong with the registry, as I tried second time a few minutes later it let me download the image. You should most definitely just wait until it operates normally, and check if address `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` is accessible for you.

Comment: And as i tried for the third time a few minutes later it says im unauthorized to download the image. There are most probably some issues right now.